# MYSQL How to keep the date data added?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new with MYSQL and PHP integration of it. So I am trying to make an Index where you can add websites and script shows the URL - Title - Last Updated Date. Till here I have no problem but I also want to keep the Date/Time the website added to the database. I am currently using TIMESTAMP but it changes the data everytime the websites updates.

Is there anything I can use for showing and storing the date when the data added?

Comment: TIMESTAMP works just fine. It won't auto-update unless you set it up that way.  Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` and show us the part that defines the column with the timestamp.

Comment: (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` text,
  `title` text,
  `uptime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

This is the part that defines the column with the timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp is currently being updated on every UPDATE. I assume it is probably defined like this:

```
date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

But you don't need the last "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Just this definition will automatically set the default value to the time the row is created, and it wont change.

```
date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: any idea how to add a new column on an existing table with this date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP? because I couldn't manage to do it

Comment: ALTER TABLE websites ADD addtime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    -> ;
ERROR 1293 (HY000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
 Gives this error when I try to add another column

Comment: Your query syntax is right, the problem is that until MySQL 5.6.5 , there can only be one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. What I would recommend is either deleting your previous timestamp column, or if you require both columns to track user changes, you will have to update it manually. So you will have to get the date and time in PHP then UPDATE it manually into your database when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Date type on the mysql table and

- when you create the record just fill the date field with php

  new Datetime('now');
- when you update a record do not enter anything in that field

  UPDATE *table* SET ULR='new_url',  (and all the other field but date added) Where something=something
- when you retrive the date from Mysql use the format method

  $date->format('Y M D hh:mm')